# How do you run a function for each row in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, dataframe

I am stuck! I have been trying to write a bit of code with Pythons Pandas lib, that will look at the value column and find a duplicate value. If it finds a duplicate value I want to execute the date-delta function to find the number of days between two amounts of the same value.

Any advice would be great!

```
            Date  Amount
0     12/27/2019     NaN
1     12/27/2019  -14.00
2     12/27/2019  -15.27
3     12/30/2019   -1.00
4     12/30/2019  -35.01
5     12/31/2019  -15.27
```

I tried something like

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(stmt, columns=['Date','Amount'])
amounts = frame['Amount']
date = frame['Date']

for x in enumerate(amounts):
    print(x)
    if x == x:
        print(x, date)
        break
```

The output

```sh
(0, nan)
(0, nan) 0       12/27/2019
1       12/27/2019
2       12/27/2019
3       12/30/2019
4       12/30/2019
           ...    
1328    06/01/2021
1329    06/01/2021
1330    06/01/2021
1331    06/01/2021
1332    06/01/2021
Name: Date, Length: 1333, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` on Amount. This will give you a list of dates for a particular amount. It should be easy call your `date-delta` function on this list.

```
df.groupby('Amount')['Date'].apply(list)
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the help I'll give it a try!

Comment: Any suggestions on pulling the list of rows for each matching amount? 

```csv
Amount
-2734.00                                [2019-12-27 00:00:00]
-1982.61                                [2019-12-27 00:00:00]
-1010.00                                [2019-12-27 00:00:00]
-600.00            [2019-12-30 00:00:00, 2019-12-30 00:00:00]
-509.00                                 [2019-12-30 00:00:00]
-307.10                                 [2020-01-03 00:00:00]
-300.00     [2020-01-03 00:00:00, 2020-01-06 00:00:00, 202...
-295.00                                 [2020-01-06 00:00:00]
```